# Key Down Event not firing in C# a geckofx 22

Tags: c#, geckofx

For some reason the Key down event is not firing in geckofx 22. The user must hold down the enter key and then release before the program will initial the keydown event on the input they are on. This has been and issue with binding as well as just plain HTML objects like text areas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use PreviewKeyDown instead of KeyDown

Cheers!